# dplyr frame_data errors with "Columns are not all same length"

Tags: r, dplyr

When I copy and paste the example from the Help page, this works OK:

```
dplyr::frame_data( 
   ~Club, ~Compensation,
   "a",   1,
   "b",   2
)
```

Yet when I try to input my own data I get the error "Columns are not all same length".

```
dplyr::frame_data( 
   ~A,    ~B,
   "NY",  "ABc"
)
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?  Here's another example with 2 rows of data:

```
soccer <- dplyr::frame_data( 
   ~A,   ~B,    ~C,        ~D,   ~E,    ~E2,
   "NY", "ABc", "Anatole", "BB", 50000, 50000,
   "NY", "CDe", "Saad",    "D",  60000, 73750
)
```

Comment: It actually happens for me with two data rows too. But the above is a minimal example

Comment: Well in that case it might be a bug.  I just looked at [the github issues](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues) and there are no open issues regarding `frame_data`.  Maybe Hadley is unaware and perhaps you should open a new issue.

Comment: OK.  Will do.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: if you step through after `debug(frame_data)` is set. You will see that the error is that there is a list output stored in `frame_columns` that looks like `list(A = c("NY", "Abc"), B = "Abc")` which `as_data_frame` rightly fails to convert to a `data_frame` in the very last line of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dplyr 0.4.3 `frame_data` does not build rectangular tables, when  `nrows != ncols`. You can check more examples [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1408). That is why you get those errors. For instance this is ok:

```
dplyr::frame_data( 
  ~A,    ~B,
  "NY",  "ABc",
  "NY", "ABC"
)
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

      A     B
  (chr) (chr)
1    NY   ABc
2    NY   ABC
```

Apparently this issue has been fixed for the [next version](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> frame_data() properly constructs rectangular tables. (#1377,
>   @kevinushey)